# How can I remove white from my backgorund layer?

Tags: shadows, shadowcatcher

[image: How can I remove this white color?]

How can I remove white from my background layer while keeping this blue color (because if I set the ground as shadow catcher I get only black shadow)?

Answer (score 0):

There was an improvement on **Shadow Catcher** so check 3.+ ... Direct and Indirect light support

For compositing you can also enable Shadow Catcher pass ...

[image]

https://www.blender.org/download/releases/3-0/  https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Cycles#Shadow_Catcher